# Logic - Is $A \rightarrow ( B \rightarrow C) $ equivalent to $A \rightarrow C$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I know that $A  \rightarrow B$ and $B  \rightarrow C$  resolves to $A  \rightarrow C$ but does $A  \rightarrow (B  \rightarrow C)$ also resolve to $A  \rightarrow C$?

Comment: For the last part, consider A : x is positive, B: y is positive, C: x+y is positive.

Comment: You should try to prove that $A\rightarrow(B\rightarrow C)$ is equivalent to $(A\wedge B)\rightarrow C$. It's handy to know

Comment: Macavity has shown that $A\rightarrow(B\rightarrow C)$ is not equivalent to $A\rightarrow C$. But one fun fact about the material conditional is that one direction of the implication does hold: $A\rightarrow C$ entails $A\rightarrow(B\rightarrow C)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No just make truthtable

```
 A | B | C || A -> (B -> C) | A -> C ||
---|---|---||---M-----------|---M----||
 T | T | T ||   T     T     |   T    ||
 T | T | F ||   F     F     |   F    ||
 T | F | T ||   T     T     |   T    ||
 T | F | F ||   T     T     |   F    || DIFFERENT
 F | T | T ||   T     T     |   T    ||
 F | T | F ||   T     F     |   T    ||
 F | F | T ||   T     T     |   T    ||
 F | F | F ||   T     T     |   T    ||
```

For A true and B,C false, A -> (B -> C) is true while A -> C is false so they are not equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this argument, in order to show that the two formulas are **not** *equivalent*.

We may consider the rule :

> if $\vdash A \rightarrow B$ and $\vdash B \rightarrow C$, then $\vdash A \rightarrow C$

and ask if we have also :

> if $\vdash A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C)$, then $\vdash A \rightarrow C$.

The answer is : **NO**.

As showed in the above truth table, the formula $(A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C)) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C)$ is not a *tautology* (for $A$ *true* and $B$ and $C$ *false*, it evaluates to *false*). So the above "proposed rule" is not sound.

Answer (score 0):

Remembering that, $$A \rightarrow  B \equiv \neg A \vee B. $$
You can reduce by DeMorgans law, $$(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow C \equiv \neg(\neg A \vee B) \vee C$$
$$(A \wedge \neg B) \vee C.$$
Can you show that the following have the same truth values given the same inputs for A and C regardless of B? $$(A \wedge \neg B) \vee C \equiv ? A \rightarrow C.$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose A true, B false, and C false.  Then [A→(B→C)] is true, but (A→C) is false.

On the other hand, if [(A→B)→C] holds true, then (B→C) holds true, and {[(A→B)→C]→(B→C)} is one axiom of a three-axiom set for propositional calculus and {(A→B)→[(B→C)→(A→C)]} is another axiom in a distinct three-axiom set for propositional calculus.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose they are equivalent. Then $\mathscr{A}=\{\neg (A\to C), A\to(B\to C)\}$ is not satisfiable. But if $\neg (A\to C)$ then we can have $A$ and $\neg C$ so if $A\to(B\to C)$, we must have $B\to C$. But $\neg C$ so $\neg B$. Thus if $A$ is true and $B$, $C$ are false, $\mathscr{A}$ is satisfied. This is a contradiction. Hence they aren't equivalent.

This argument was produced using a [tableau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux), a systematic search for contradictions; look:

[image].

Comment: The code for the diagram above can be found [here](https://www.writelatex.com/726768qphvyp#/1568016/).

Answer (score 0):

$A \to (B \to C)$ says that, if you know $A$ is true, then $B \to C$. So it says that if you know $A$ and $B$ are true, then $C$ is true.

On the other hand, $A \to C$ says that if you know $A$ is true, then $C$ must be true - with no restriction on $B$.

In general, $A \to (B\to C)$ is actually equivalent to $(A \land B) \to C$. The equivalence between these goes by the name "Currying".